# Return the number of succeeding nodes per node in networkx

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

I would like to know how many edges are succeeding each node in a network. I have created a graph of 20 nodes, but it should preferably work for any number of nodes. The code is given here, and a picture of the graph is also shown.

```
def create_graph(number_of_nodes):
        # Set seed to get reproducible graph
        seed = 10
        random.seed(seed)
        np.random.seed(seed)

        # Create a random tree with x nodes
        global G
        G = nx.random_tree(number_of_nodes, seed=seed)
        pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot', root=0)

        # Draw the graph
        nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
        plt.show()
        return G


create_graph(20)
```

[Picture showing the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKdKP.png)

I have some code that works when the graph is smaller, i.e. doesn't have many branches. However, it is not working on this example with 20 nodes.

```
# Dictionaries for traversing
d = dict(nx.bfs_successors(graph, root_node))
print(d.items())

key_to_value_lengths = {k: len(v) for k, v in d.items()}
print(key_to_value_lengths)

edges_succeeding = {}
total_removed = 0

for k, v in key_to_value_lengths.items():
    total = sum(key_to_value_lengths.values())
    edges_succeeding[k] = total - total_removed
    total_removed = total_removed + key_to_value_lengths[k]

print("Number of edges succeeding " + str(edges_succeeding))
```

The output I get is this:

```
    Number of edges succeeding {0: 19, 6: 17, 14: 16, 15: 15, 16: 12, 10: 11, 1: 10, 2: 8, 5: 7, 7: 6, 8: 5, 11: 4, 18: 3, 13: 1}
```

So it is correct for the first few nodes, but ends up wrong after node 16, because it also includes the branch on the other side (after node 10).

I want the dictionary `edges_succeeding` to return the number of edges succeeding that node, on that given branch. E.g. the correct for node 16 would be `16: 8`, not `16: 12`

Preferably it should also be able to scale this up and down for any given size of the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should solve your problem. Steps to reach the solution

1. I used depth-first-search (dfs) instead of breadth-first-search (bfs), because we want to process the nodes from the highest level to the lowest level (if we think of the dfs-tree). So first step is to create the `dfs_tree` and calculating the depth of the nodes.
2. Creating processing order of nodes (`ordered_nodes`): As already mentioned we want to process the nodes by the level in the `dfs-tree`, because the highest level are those nodes with 0 succeeding edges. Starting from those nodes we can iteratively calculate the number of edges to the second highest level by counting the number of edges to the nodes with highest level.
3. This is exactly the purpose of the `for node in ordered_nodes` loop. Iteratively calculating the succeeding edges from highest level to lowest level (i.e. root node).

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import random

def create_graph(number_of_nodes):
    # Set seed to get reproducible graph
    seed = 10
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

    # Create a random tree with x nodes
    G = nx.random_tree(number_of_nodes, seed=seed)
    return G


graph = create_graph(20)

# 1 dfs-tree and node levels
# dictionary to store the "depth" or level or each node
levels = {0: 0}
# directed dfs tree to store the predecessors
dfs_tree = nx.DiGraph()
for u, v in nx.dfs_edges(graph, 0):
    levels[v] = levels[u] + 1
    dfs_tree.add_edge(u, v)

print(levels)
# {0: 0, 17: 1, 6: 1, 14: 2, 15: 3, 12: 4, 16: 4, 1: 5, 4: 6, 5: 6, 8: 7, 18: 8, 3: 9, 13: 9, 9: 10, 10: 4, 2: 5, 7: 6, 11: 7, 19: 8}

# 2 sorting nodes
# process nodes by highest level first
ordered_nodes = sorted(graph.nodes, key=lambda node: levels[node], reverse=True)

# 3 iteratively calculation
# final dict
edges_succeeeding = {}
for node in ordered_nodes:
    if graph.degree(node) == 1:
        # add lowest entry to the dict
        edges_succeeeding[node] = 0

    # start adding information about the predecessor
    for predecessor in dfs_tree.predecessors(node):
        edges_succeeeding[predecessor] = edges_succeeeding.get(predecessor, 0) + edges_succeeeding[node] + 1

print(edges_succeeeding)
# {9: 0, 13: 1, 3: 0, 18: 3, 8: 4, 19: 0, 11: 1, 5: 5, 7: 2, 4: 0, 1: 7, 2: 3, 16: 8, 10: 4, 15: 15, 12: 0, 14: 16, 6: 17, 0: 19, 17: 0}
```